# Multisite wide post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite

Is it possible to have a multisite wide post type without duplicating the posts? That is a post type that is the same no matter what blog you are on?

*Theoretical example:* StackExchange has many sites (blogs) but wants their site-wide news post type, I'll call it `sitewide_news`, to be the same on every blog. If they happen to be in blog id 4 and make a change or add a new post it will show up in 3 or 8 as if they made the change there. In other words only one database entry exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/), which works really, really well.