# Multisite with a single, shared custom post type, while retaining site URL

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, url-rewriting

Small multisite setup, two very different sites, both need to access an `event` custom post type. I don't want to duplicate posts (there are some plugins that "broadcast" a post to the network).

`switch_to_blog(1)` will get me part way there, where `blog 1` is the "master" blog that contains the `event` data, as far as archive-style pages that list all the events. But my concern is that the URL/permalink of the event, when viewed from `blog 2` will point to `blog 1`, and following that permalink will then take the user to the other blog, confusing the user.

Is there a solution (possibly using rewrite) that would allow an event post at `//blog1/events/event1` to appear as `//blog2/events/event1` when viewed from `blog 2`?

Comment: You might want to take a look here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11276/multisite-wide-post-type - that would be a different approach.

Comment: I've already been there, and that's why I created this question specifically. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Register the CPT on blog 2 with `'show_ui' => FALSE`. Hook on blog 1 into `save_post` and copy the data to blog 2.

   - Pro: You can search in those posts. Correct templates will be used automatically.
   - Con: Duplicated data are always a little bit … dirty.
2. [Register an endpoint](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91195/73) with an URL scheme like the CPT on blog 1 (`EP_ROOT`).

   - Pro: No duplicated data.
   - Con: You have to implement the template logic manually to load the correct theme file. And search will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Decide which blog will contain the "data of record", use `"show_ui" => false` on the other blog(s) and then modify queries that deal with that post to use the appopriate table prefix. The data will still be populated within the context of whatever blog you're viewing (ie: `site_url()` will work as expected, and your templates and theme will be correct - assuming you're using different templates and themes for different blogs), and you won't have duplicated data anywhere.

The downside is that in a scenario with a very large network of blogs, this might become unmanageable.

It also means that you must have access to the "blog of record" in order to be able to enter and update the post data, unless you're also prepared to hook into the `save_post` action of all the other blogs and fool them into writing the data to the other blog's tables. You would then also need to fudge that post type's List Tables and edit-post request as well, which is daunting to say the least.

This solution works in the case of a piece of content that will be maintained by an administrator with access to the primary blog, but needs to be posted to or visible on other blogs on the network; it is not appropriate for content that will be created by admins/users of other blogs on the network to be shared with the other blogs on that network. For that approach, see [toscho's answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102095/3687).